# Devise user levels theory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I started a application with Devise (2.1.2). I'm trying to figure out how I want the user roles. It goes like this:

A user registers on the website, this is only possible if this user has been invited by another user. (the user who registers need an invite code). This user will then start in Level 1, and can through jobs in the application to higher levels by working to earn experience points. The highest level will be level 10.

I would also like to have a moderator level where the moderators jobs that users submit review. But these moderators are normal users and also just start at level 1.

Second, to invite another user is only possible in level 2 and higher you get, the more users you can invite. Now you can not unlimited users remain uitnodigigen but for example: in level 2 but a user and only 2 level 3 level 4 users and you can invite users and 2 in level 5 you can invite 5 users.

I hope my theory is possible and that somebody is able to walk me trough some code and discuss my theory possibilities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For an exhaustive and relatively future proof mechanism, use the following:

1. Devise - for Authentication - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
2. Cancan - for Authorization - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan
3. Rolify - for Roles Library - https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Here is a tutorial on how to use the three together: https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial

Interestingly, the tutorial addresses a problem statement very similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Look for CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan - this will solve everything you want